# OpenCV: charuco (diamonds) not working on bigger images. Which parameters to tune?

Tags: opencv, markers, aruco

somehow detecting charuco diamonds does not work with bigger images for me. With my original images of 1920x1080 it neither recognizes the ids reliably (the diamond ids elements are switching places every time). In the first image, you can see it recognizes (7, 9, 45, 2).

[image: 1920x1080 image. wrong ids order and pose estimation]

Then I tried downsampling the images to 960x540, and dividing the calibration params, f, c, to half, and it works! The id is correctly recognized as (2,7,45,9) and the pose estimation is accurate.

[image: 960x540 image. correctly estimated]

How to make it work for bigger images? I tried changing the detection parameters depending on absolute pixel units (not relative to image size). Here is a list of my current parameters. I realized increasing the Window size for threasholding helps recognizing the squares, but not for id or pose estimation.

`nmarkers: 1024
adaptiveThreshWinSizeMin: 13
adaptiveThreshWinSizeMax: 113
adaptiveThreshWinSizeStep: 10
adaptiveThreshWinSize: 42
adaptiveThreshConstant: 7
minMarkerPerimeterRate: 0.1
maxMarkerPerimeterRate: 4.0
polygonalApproxAccuracyRate: 0.05
minCornerDistance: 10.0
minDistanceToBorder: 10
minMarkerDistance: 10.0
minMarkerDistanceRate: 0.05
doCornerRefinement: false
cornerRefinementWinSize: 5
cornerRefinementMaxIterations: 30
cornerRefinementMinAccuracy: 0.1
markerBorderBits: 1
perspectiveRemovePixelPerCell: 8
perspectiveRemoveIgnoredMarginPerCell: 0.13
maxErroneousBitsInBorderRate: 0.04
minOtsuStdDev: 5.0
errorCorrectionRate: 0.6`

Any hints?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At the end I needed to patch the opencv aruco module. It was a matter of a certain treshold escalating too fast (to the 4th) to the image size (`closestCandidateDistance` in `refineDetectedMarkers`). The solution was to make `minRepDistance` in `detectCharucoDiamond` to only scale linearly with the image size.

Full answer and patch in the [opencv forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/170924/aruco-diamonds-not-working-on-bigger-images-which-parameters-to-tune/?answer=171465#post-id-171465).